Is it true that this quadruple sum involving $f(x,y,z,p)=x^p+y^p−z^p$, is equal to the sequence $1,0,0,0,...$ only if $p=1$ or $p=2$?
Consider the sum:
$$s(n) = \sum _{k=1}^n \left(\sum _{z=1}^n \left(\sum _{y=1}^n \left(\sum _{x=1}^n g(k)\left[\gcd (f(x,y,z,p),n)=k\right]\right)\right)\right)\label{1}\tag{1}$$
where

the minimal Weierstrass equation is: $$f(x,y,z,p) = x^p+y^p-z^p,$$
$[\;]$ is the Iverson bracket, and
$g(k)$ is the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function, sometimes denoted as:
$$g(k) = \varphi^{-1}(k) = \sum_{d \mid k} \mu(d)d.$$

Question

Is it true that the sum in \eqref{1} is equal to the sequence $s(n) = 1,0,0,0,...$ for $n=1,2,3,4,...$ only if $p=1$ or $p=2$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#Modular_functions

"Modular functions:  When the weight k is zero, it can be shown using
Liouville's theorem that the only modular forms are constant
functions."

Data supporting the claim:
For $p=0:$
{1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000, 1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 
3375, 4096, 4913, 5832, 6859, 8000, 9261, 10648, 12167, 13824, 15625, 
17576, 19683, 21952, 24389, 27000, 29791, 32768, 35937, 39304, 42875, 
46656, 50653, 54872, 59319, 64000, 68921, 74088}
For $p=1:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
For $p=2:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
For $p=3:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 780, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2394, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3720, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14652, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}
For $p=4:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, -40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 936, 0, 0, 0, 1632, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -5000, 0, 0, 0, -8120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2664, 0, 0, 
0, 49200, 0}
For $p=5:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -330, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -30690, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44280, 0}
For $p=6:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -624, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2736, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -14880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -69264, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0}
For $p=7:$
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7308, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
Mathematica 14
Clear[g, n, f, p, nn]
g[n_]:= Total[MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]*Divisors[n]];
(*g[n_]= Total[MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]*Divisors[n]];*)
nn = 42;
p = 0;
f = x^p + y^p - z^p;
ParallelTable[
 Sum[Sum[Sum[
    Sum[If[GCD[f, n] == k, 1, 0]*g[k], {x, 1, n}], {y, 1, n}], {z, 1, 
    n}], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]
p = 1;
f = x^p + y^p - z^p;
ParallelTable[
 Sum[Sum[Sum[
    Sum[If[GCD[f, n] == k, 1, 0]*g[k], {x, 1, n}], {y, 1, n}], {z, 1, 
    n}], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]
p = 2;
f = x^p + y^p - z^p;
ParallelTable[
 Sum[Sum[Sum[
    Sum[If[GCD[f, n] == k, 1, 0]*g[k], {x, 1, n}], {y, 1, n}], {z, 1, 
    n}], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]
p = 3;
f = x^p + y^p - z^p;
ParallelTable[
 Sum[Sum[Sum[
    Sum[If[GCD[f, n] == k, 1, 0]*g[k], {x, 1, n}], {y, 1, n}], {z, 1, 
    n}], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]

Matrices hiding inside \eqref{1}:
$p=0$

$p=1$

$p=2$

$p=3$

Compare nonzero pattern with:
https://oeis.org/A051731

Given the form $x^p+y^p-z^p$, I suspect that this may have to do with Fermat's Last Theorem.

Related question posted at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/477204/25104 and earlier: https://mathoverflow.net/q/456149/25104

Published in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A368197

Outline/long comment:
\begin{align*}
s(n) &= \sum_{z=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^n \sum_{x=1}^n g \bigl( \gcd (f(x,y,z,p),n) \bigr) \\
&= \sum_{z=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^n \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{d\mid \gcd (f(x,y,z,p),n)} d\mu(d) \\
&= \sum_{d\mid n} d\mu(d) \sum_{z=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^n \sum_{x=1}^n [d\mid f(x,y,z,p)] \\
&= \sum_{d\mid n} d\mu(d) \sum_{z=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^n \sum_{x=1}^n [x^p+y^p\equiv z^p\pmod d] = n^3 \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} F_p(d),
\end{align*}
where $F_p(d)$ is the number of solutions of $x^p+y^p\equiv z^p\pmod d$ in ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ of residue classes modulo $d$. This is a multiplicative function by the Chinese remainder theorem, so we can further write
$$
s(n) = n^3 \prod_{q\mid n} \biggl( 1 - \frac{F_p(q)}{q^2} \biggr).
$$
So the problem is equivalent to: Is $F_p(q) = q^2$ for all primes $q$? The answer is clearly yes for $p=1$, presumably yes for $p=2$ (the argument is escaping me right now), and (both from the data and from general principles) probably false for $p\ge3$ and I would look specifically at primes $q\equiv1\pmod p$ for counterexamples.

Thank you! And thank you for mentioning residue classes and the Chinese remainder theorem.

I forgot to mention the pink box comment by Michel Marcus, which can be found if you  click on history in https://oeis.org/A368197
https://i.sstatic.net/FyLuJGTV.png
https://oeis.org/A367689
